# Redundant State Call OpenGL

Tags: ios, objective-c, opengl-es

I am using OpenGL to draw arrays in several different objects. Each object is drawing different data, but for each object the container/location for the data remains constant for the entire life of the program. OpenGL is telling me I have a number of redundant state calls:

- glBindFramebuffer
- glUniformMatrix4fv
- glUniform4fv
- glBindRenderbuffer

of these, I am only explicitly calling glUniformMatrix4fv and glUniform4fv. After seeing this, I tried to move these so they were only called during the setup of OpenGL, but the arrays weren't getting drawn.

Currently this is a sample of what is getting called each time it redraws:

```
glBindVertexArrayOES(_vertexArray);
glUseProgram(_program);
glUniformMatrix4fv(_mvpMatrixHandle,1,0,_mvpMatrix.m);
glUniform4fv(_colorHandle,1,colors);
glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLE_FAN,0,4);
```

**Questions**:

1. Because the container and location of the variables I am passing to these functions, do these need to be called each time I draw the arrays for a given object or only once at the beginning of the program? If so, how can I do this?
2. How can I eliminate these other redundant state calls that I am not explicitly calling?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Any data you pass to the shader may be passed only once if the value does not change. Although totally possible I will suggest you not to do that simply because such code is harder to maintain. If at some point you choose to change the matrix for instance it will give you trouble of restructuring. So do that only in very late development state and rather only if you need to gain performance (not that this will make much of a difference though). There are other ways to handle these things but firs...

If the objects are not drawn when you move the matrix call then either the matrix is not setup correctly or more possible situation is you forgot to use the shader program before the call. (`glUseProgram(_program);`)

Since you say you are not binding the buffer yourself and still get the redundant warnings you are probably using some higher level tools such as GLKView(controller) which internally does that for you. You will be unable to lose those warnings and I suggest you not to use those tools at all. The only thing that is useful from the GLKit are the matrix and some vector operations from my experience.

So about your redundant calls and "other ways". What some do is rather check the current state that was sent to the shader and compare if the new value differs from the current. This is not as easy as it seems since some values should be per-shader and some per-context. For instance if you enable the alpha blending it will effect all the shaders and you should check and assign the value on the context object. On the other hand if you are setting an uniform such as a matrix you should check and assign it on the shader you are using. This takes a bit of work but is worth it to get a nice clean code: You should create wrappers for a shader object and for the context object. Those should also carry the states of certain parameters when they are assigned and check the new value before assigning:

```
- (void)setMatrix:(GLKMatrix4)matrix
{
    if(memcmp(currentMatrix.m, matrix.m, sizeof(matrix.m)) != 0) { // will return 0 if they are the same
        memcpy(currentMatrix.m, matrix.m, sizeof(matrix.m)); // copy the new data
        glUniformMatrix4fv(_mvpMatrixHandle, 1, 0, matrix.m); // send data to shader
    }
}
```

This should then be done for all the calls you are using. It will prevent any redundant calls even if you call them every time but will produce a small overhead on the CPU due to the memory compare. Still this is extremely small overhead.